# Iframe video not play on mobile when page load

Tags: iframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOs7b.png)Why not play iframe video in mobile.And how to play video in loop.Can somebody tell me where i wrong.

This is my code.

```
 <div id="player"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MquYqKctLe8?&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=MquYqKctLe8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: You should provide at least some code

Comment: Sorry @lars i can't understand what you are write

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: I updated the code please check it.